# My Pygame window wont close. How do i fix this?

Tags: python

I was following a tutorial by techwithtim (link:https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=waY3LfJhQLY&t=442s)
but The window i open wont close heres my code
import pygame
import time
import random

```
width = 500
height = 500
WIN = pygame.display.set_mode((width,height))
pygame.display.set_caption("piss")

def main():
    run = True
    while run:
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                run == False
                break
    pygame.quit()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

i tried to click the X in the corner, it didnt work.

Comment: **`run = False`**  instead of `run == False`

Comment: The way i formated the question was a bit off

Answer (score 2):

```
if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
    run == False
```

Should be `run = False`.

The Python `=` operator assigns values to a variable. The `==` operator checks if both values match.